# What is your favorite feature of SharePoint SUSHI?

Tags: open-source, community

Please share, what is your favorite feature of SUSHI?

Myself and my team have worked hard over the past four years to build [SharePoint SUSHI](http://sushi.codeplex.com/), one of the most popular SharePoint utilities on codeplex. SUSHI has been downloaded an amazing 30,000 times. We have done this completely for your benefit and completely for free. We would like your feedback. How do you use SUSHI?  Where are you from if you don't mind sharing and what type of company do you work for?  It is rewarding as an open source developer to see your many hours of uncompensated labor put to good use.

Comment: sorry mate, before you mentioned it, i had never seen this app before. good job with it though, it looks professional. most sharepoint clients i deal with don't allow third party executables to be run on production farms. :(

Comment: It looks nice enough, is it for SP2010, or also compatible with SP2007? Based on the screenshot, I guess you can use it on a client/workstation and connect with an SP farm?

Comment: This is new to me, but it looks like something ill definitely try out when I get time. Thanks for contributing to the community on your spare time :)

Comment: i have never heard of SUSHI before, however it looks very interesting and promising. are you looking for developers to join this project, because i would be very interested :-)

Comment: It is great, and i like it very much! i have a question that is can it support mulit-sites backup at the same time?

Comment: Never heard of it before either, though the Profile Image Importer is a requirement I've seen before, could prove useful. Does that sync to the User Profile store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Security Reports](http://sushi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security%20Reports&referringTitle=Home)

I've found security reports the most useful over the years.  The ability to see everything a user has access to and all memberships in SharePoint all from one place has come in handy countless times.